# Are the contours of every plane parallel to the x-z plane of a function F, circles?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let:

$F(x,y,z) = x^2-3y^2+z^2 $

I know that this is a hyperboloid in $R^3$ and is oriented in a way that the contours are indeed circles, but I haven't the first idea on showing the result.

Comment: I think your hyperboloid takes the form $F(x,y,z)=c$ for some constant c?

Comment: Big hint: what does a slice of F by a plane $y=k$ for some constant $k$ look like, as a function $G(x,z)$?  What do $G$'s contours - that is, the equations of the form $G(x,z)=c$ - look like?

Comment: What I can see is:

$F(x,y,z) + 3y^2 = x^2 + z^2$

and the RHS is an equation of a circle.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're saying that the level curves form a hyperboloid.  Let's exam one of those level curves by setting $F(x, y, z) = c$

On the x-y plane (z=0), we have $x^2-3y^2 = c$, which is clearly a hyperbola.

On the y-z plane (x=0), we have $-3y^2+z^2 = c$, which is clearly another hyperbola.

On the x-z plane (y=0), we have $x^2+z^2 = c$, which is a circle.